# Comparison in C#: operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'

Tags: c#, generics

I have created a **`BinaryTreeNode<T>`** class and then creating **`Add(T data)`** method for **`BinaryTree<T>`** class.

When I try to compare Values of objects compiler says:

> **operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'**.

Example:

```
  public void AddNode(T data) {
        BinaryTreeNode<T> node = new BinaryTreeNode<T>(data);
        BinaryTreeNode<T> temp = root;

        if (temp.Value < node.Value) // **PROBLEM HERE**
        ...
```

I'm using VS08 Express Edition.

Comment: Do you actually have a class named "T"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should add a constraint such that T must implement `IComparable<T>` and then use that:

```
public class BinaryTree<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    public void AddNode(T data)
    {
        BinaryTreeNode<T> node = new BinaryTreeNode<T>(data);
        BinaryTreeNode<T> temp = root;

        if (temp.Value.CompareTo(node.Value) < 0)
        ...
```

An alternative is to pass in an `IComparer<T>` and use that:

```
public class BinaryTree<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    private readonly IComparer<T> comparer;

    public BinaryTree(IComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        this.comparer = comparer;
        ...
    }

    public void AddNode(T data)
    {
        BinaryTreeNode<T> node = new BinaryTreeNode<T>(data);
        BinaryTreeNode<T> temp = root;

        if (comparer.Compare(temp.Value, node.Value) < 0)
```

This is the closest you can get to guaranteeing a "<" operator - overloaded operators are static, and there's no way of constraining a type argument to require it.

Comment: Awesome.I should have asked before 3hrs :-). Would you please add on how to implement IComparable<T> for Ts that dont implement it.

Comment: If T itself doesn't implement `IComparable<T>` then you probably want to use the `IComparer<T>` approach instead - it's pretty simple to implement, you just compare the given values and return a negative number, a positive number or 0 depending on that comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Look into using [Generic Constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) to narrow down the types that T can be. That way you can ensure that they can be compared using your operator.

At the moment T could be *any* object. For instance, if you had a Car object, how would the compiler know what to make of saying one Car is "less than" or "greater than" another? That is why you need constraints.

Comment: Thanks.You removed doubts about why they can't be compared.(+1)

Answer (score 1):

The type (int, string, char[], MyClass, YourClass, etc) of Value doesn't support the '<' operation. That is normal for most non-intrinsic number types, i.e. int, long, decimal, etc.

T needs to implement the IComparable class so it can be compared with other object of type T.

So, you function declaration must enforce a constraint on T:

```
public class BinaryTree<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    public void AddNode(T data)
```

and you must make sure that whatever T is, it must implement IComparable.

```
public class MyData : IComparable<MyData>
{
    public int CompareTo(MyData other)
    {
         // return -1 if 'this' is smaller than other, 0 if equals, 1 otherwise
    }
}
```

In your add function, you then call

```
if( temp.Value.CompareTo(node.Value) < 0 )
```