# Difference between interface inheritance and generic constraints

Tags: c#

I have the **following code in C#**:

1)

```
public class MyBinaryTree<TItem> where TItem : IComparable<TItem>
{ ... };
```

2)

```
public class MyBinaryTree<TItem> : IComparable<TItem>
{ ... };
```

[I found this sample at this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308002/comparision-problem-in-c-sharp), but it is not *entirely the way* I want.

The first example/code tells us that **item (TItem) implements the interface IComparable**.

The second example/code tells us that our whole **class (MyBinaryTree) implements the interface IComparable**.

I do not understand it very well.
The first example I've never used and the second I use often (this is a classic example of the interface). Some advice - supplements?

How does it **apply in practice**?

Comment: Is there is real code question here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is that the second example is interface inheritance. The second is [constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) on what the generic type can be.

Interface inheritance means that the class that inherits that interface MUST provide implementations (unless it is abstract) of the methods contained within the interface. So, this essentially imposes constraints on the class and how it is built

Constraints on the other hand, impose constraints on the generic type that is used within the class. This allows the implementation to be able to make certain assumptions as to what TItem will be allowed to do within the class.

Examples:

**Inheritance**

```
public class IComparableImplemented : IComparable<T>
{
   //MUST implement CompareTo
   public int CompareTo(T other)
   {
       //Compare stuff
   }
}
```

**Type Constraints**

```
public class ClassUsingConstraints<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
   public static void method(T stuff)
   {
       stuff.CompareTo(stuff);  
   }
}
```

So, you will notice that **inheritance forces the class to implement a method**. Whereas type constraints do not force anything on the class implementation. Instead, **type constraints force that `T` must implement `IComparable`**. So, that way you can rely on `T` having access to the `CompareTo` method

Answer (score 0):

The statements aren't really comparable! Pun intended

One as you say is a classic implementation, the other is saying to be a valid entry in the MyBinaryTree collection, the member must implement the interface.

```
public class MyBinaryTree<TItem> where TItem : IComparable<TItem>
```

could have easily been

```
public class MyBinaryTree<TItem> where TItem : int;
{
}
```

It's only choosing to use IComparable in both statements that is leading to your furrowed brow.